# geom_bracket over facets with external data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know this has been asked before but the answers seem quite hackey. I was hoping someone had another good idea.

I am trying to add a bracket (maybe using `geom_bracket` ?) over two facets but I can't figure out how to get it to work. All the data required (e.g. xmin, xmax, etc.) comes from a separate dataframe.

Here's the ggplot

```
colours <- c("NCS_Con" = "#f77f00", "NCS_PNS" = "#d62828", "CS_Con" = "#fcbf49", "CS_PNS" = "#EAE2B7")

p1 <- ggplot(corttestunitedmutated, aes(x = Treatment_Status, y = mean)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Treatment_Status),
           colour = "black",
           stat = "identity", 
           position = position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se),
                width = .2,
                position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  facet_grid(.~c.d.Sex.,
             scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() + theme(strip.background  = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
                     panel.border = element_blank(),
                     axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
                     axis.text.x=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(title = "Corticosterone",
       y = "mean plasma [corticosterone] (pg/ml)",
       x = "Status\nTreatment") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours,
                    labels=c("- PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n- Chronic Stress", "- PNS\n+ Chronic Stress", "+ PNS\n+ Chronic Stress"))
```

This is what that looks like. Exactly what I want:

[image: barplot]

This is the dataframe for the brackets

```
stattest5
  c.d.Sex.  group1  group2 yposition asterisk
1     Male  CS_Con  CS_Con  902.2499       ••
3     Male NCS_Con NCS_Con  851.3016      •••



dput(stattest5)
> dput(stattest5)
structure(list(c.d.Sex. = c("Male", "Male"), group1 = c("CS_Con", 
"NCS_Con"), group2 = c("CS_Con", "NCS_Con"), yposition = c(902.249860035171, 
851.301636108547), asterisk = c("••", "•••")), row.names = c(1L, 
3L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(`2` = 2L, 
`4` = 4L), class = "omit"))
```

This is the data for the ggplot:

```
dput(corttestunitedmutated)
dput(corttestunitedmutated)
structure(list(Treatment_Status = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("NCS_Con", "NCS_PNS", "CS_Con", "CS_PNS"
), class = "factor"), c.d.Sex. = c("Female", "Male", "Female", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"), N = c(9L, 10L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 9L, 10L), mean = c(793.185103222222, 415.2964824, 
491.711204444444, 337.354349777778, 828.866709611111, 470.6272386, 
617.146221777778, 521.39674985), sd = c(139.479678927179, 183.047203537505, 
115.471138211954, 78.2702347304746, 176.119561017744, 132.014450160878, 
167.489275167574, 181.880434256998), se = c(46.4932263090596, 
57.8846082502948, 38.4903794039847, 26.0900782434915, 58.7065203392481, 
41.7466346563155, 55.8297583891913, 57.5156434072629), ypos = c(851.301636108547, 
487.652242712868, 539.824178699425, 369.966947582142, 902.249860035171, 
522.810531920394, 686.933419764267, 593.291304109079)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've tried shifting the data around, so group1 and group2 are the sex like this:

```
stattest5
    Group group1 group2 yposition asterisk
1  CS_Con Female   Male  902.2499       ••
3 NCS_Con Female   Male  851.3016      •••

dput(stattest5.2)
> dput(stattest5.2)
structure(list(Group = c("CS_Con", "NCS_Con"), group1 = c("Female", 
"Female"), group2 = c("Male", "Male"), yposition = c(902.249860035171, 
851.301636108547), asterisk = c("••", "•••")), row.names = c(1L, 
3L), class = "data.frame", na.action = structure(c(`2` = 2L, 
`4` = 4L), class = "omit"))
```

But I get this error message

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (4): label, xmin, xmax, y.position, group, step.increase, vjust, bracket.nudge.y, bracket.shorten, x and y
```

Here's an ugly mock-up of what I'm after (I can adjust the size and spacing after).

[image: ugly mock up]

If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I think your "ugly mock up" looks pretty good...

You *can* use `geom_bracket`, but not between facets. That would definitely require a hacky approach.

Fortunately, you can rearrange your plot to have gender on the x axis, with the fill variable still dodged, so it will look essentially the same but on a single facet.

The remaining problem is that `geom_bracket` doesn't seem to behave too well with `position_dodge`, so we still need a little factor-to-numeric hack:

```r
x <- factor(stattest.5.2$Group, 
            levels = levels(corttestunitedmutated$Treatment_Status))
stattest.5.2$Group  <- (as.numeric(x) - 2.5)/4
```

Now we can plot:

```r
ggplot(corttestunitedmutated, 
       aes(x = c.d.Sex., y = mean, fill = Treatment_Status)) + 
  geom_bar(colour = "black", stat = "identity", width = 0.7,
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se), width = .2,
                position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  ggpubr::geom_bracket(aes(xmin = 1 + Group, xmax= 2 + Group, 
                           y.position = yposition,
                           label = asterisk), 
                       data = stattest.5.2,,
                       inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme( strip.background  = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
         panel.border = element_blank(),
         axis.ticks = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
         panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
         axis.text.x.top = element_text(size = 12),
         legend.position = "bottom") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  labs(title = "Corticosterone",
        y = "mean plasma [corticosterone] (pg/ml)",
        x = "Status\nTreatment") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours,
                    labels=c("- PNS\n- Chronic Stress", 
                             "+ PNS\n- Chronic Stress", 
                             "- PNS\n+ Chronic Stress", 
                             "+ PNS\n+ Chronic Stress"))
```

[image]

Personally, I think you are getting a nicer look with the manually edited plot. You can get a similar look by drawing lines over the plot use `grid::grid.draw(grid::linesGrob(...))`, but this will take a lot of trial-and error to get right.

An example of this approach would be to first left join your two data frames and plot vertical segments using `geom_segment` at the "legs" of the brackets:

```r
p1 <- corttestunitedmutated %>% 
        left_join(stattest5[-1], by = c(Treatment_Status = "group1")) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = Treatment_Status, y = mean)) + 
        geom_bar(aes(fill = Treatment_Status),
                 colour = "black",
                 stat = "identity", 
                 position = position_dodge()) +
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - se, ymax = mean + se),
                      width = .2,
                      position = position_dodge(.9)) +
        geom_segment(aes(xend = Treatment_Status, y = ypos, 
                         yend = yposition + 100)) +
        scale_fill_manual(values = colours,
                          labels = c("- PNS\n- Chronic Stress", 
                                     "+ PNS\n- Chronic Stress", 
                                     "- PNS\n+ Chronic Stress", 
                                     "+ PNS\n+ Chronic Stress")) +
        facet_grid(.~c.d.Sex., scales = "free_x") +
        theme_bw() + 
        theme(strip.background  = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "grey80"),
              panel.border = element_blank(),
              axis.ticks = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
              panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
              axis.text.x=element_blank(),
              legend.position = "bottom") +
        labs(title = "Corticosterone",
             y = "mean plasma [corticosterone] (pg/ml)",
             x = "Status\nTreatment")
```

Then effectively draw the horizontal lines and asterisk markers manually in grid:

```
library(grid)

p1
grid.draw(linesGrob(x = unit(c(0.149, 0.606), "npc"), 
                    y = unit(c(0.87, 0.87), "npc"),
                    gp = gpar(lwd = 1.5)))
grid.draw(linesGrob(x = unit(c(0.36, 0.818), "npc"), 
                    y = unit(c(0.834, 0.834), "npc"),
                    gp = gpar(lwd = 1.5)))
grid.draw(textGrob(label = "**",
                   x = unit(c(0.606 + 0.149)/2, "npc"),
                   y = unit(0.883, "npc"),
                   gp = gpar(cex = 2)))
grid.draw(textGrob(label = "***",
                   x = unit(0.57, "npc"),
                   y = unit(0.849, "npc"),
                   gp = gpar(cex = 2)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you - I should add the mock up was done manually by annotating the exported figure.

Unfortunately, rearranging the figure isn't really a good option for me because I have other stats in the Male/ Female groups. I actually had it your suggested way around before but ended up having to change it so I could get the other stats on. Can you tell me a little more about the `grid::grid.draw(grid::linesGrob(...))` ?